# Concise way to draw this pyramid

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics3d, code-review

[image]

I wrote the following to draw a pyramid, this approach uses functions `TranslationTransform` and `Tuples`, is there a way to do the same thing more concise? Maybe `Table`, `Nest`, `ArrayPad` is useful.

```
cubes = {
   {c1 = Cuboid[]},
   TranslationTransform[{##, -1}][c1] & @@@ Tuples[{-1, 1}/2, 2],
   TranslationTransform[{##, -2}][c1] & @@@ Tuples[{-1, 0, 1}, 2],
   TranslationTransform[{##, -3}][c1] & @@@ Tuples[{-3, -1, 1, 3}/2, 2],
   TranslationTransform[{##, -4}][c1] & @@@ Tuples[{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}, 2]
   };
Graphics3D[cubes]
```

Thank you all.

Comment: Please don't include the answer in your question -- post it as an answer, instead.

Comment: @DavidRicherby All right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
n = 5;
Graphics3D[Table[Cuboid[{#[[1]], #[[2]], -i}] & /@ Tuples[Range[-i/2, i/2], 2], 
 {i, 0, n - 1}]]
```

[image]

A more concise version (thanks: Vitaliy Kaurov):

```
Graphics3D[Table[Cuboid[{#, #2, -i}] & @@@ Tuples[Range[-i/2, i/2], 2], {i, 0, n - 1}]]
```

Comment: NIce +1 ! For code-golf i'd pack this as `Graphics3D[Table[Cuboid[{#1,#2,-i}]&@@@Tuples[Range[-i,i]/2,2], {i,0,4}]]` ;-) I deleted my answer, it was essentially the same.

Comment: Thank you @Vitaliy. Updated with you suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by @kglr, now I got another simpler way

```
Graphics3D[Table[Cuboid[{x,y,-z}],{z,0,4},{y,-z/2,z/2},{x,-z/2,z/2}]]
```

or

```
Graphics3D[Table[{Cuboid[{x-z/2,y-z/2,-z}]},{z,5},{y,z},{x,z}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Not concise

```
n = 7;

Standardize[GraphEmbedding@GridGraph@#, Mean, 1&] & /@ Array[{#,#}&, n] // 
Cuboid /@ Join@@MapIndexed[Append[#1, - First@#2 +.5]&, #, {2}] & // Graphics3D
```

[image]

but fun to play with:

```
 n = 20;

 Standardize[ #(CycleGraph@#~GraphEmbedding~"CircularEmbedding"), Mean, 1&] & /@ Array[#&, n] // 
 Ball /@ Join@@MapIndexed[Append[#1, - 1.5 First@#2 +.5]&, #, {2}] & // Graphics3D
```

[image]